# How to build and get building errors in eclipse for specific package

Tags: eclipse, ant, build

I have 3 different packages, let's say :

```
com.pack.*
com.package.commons.*
com.package.app.*
```

The thing is, these 3 packages are in the same source folder and I can't move them.

- My `com.pack` is completely independant, let's say it's my framework.
- My `com.package.commons` can import classes from `com.pack` ONLY.
- My last package can import whichever classes it needs.

In my eclipse project everything is thing as long as I'm the only one to develop, I know I can't import anything without checking first where it comes from.
But I work in a team and errors happen frequently, I've tried to make an Ant Build that will first build my framework then my commons (with the framework in it's CP during build time) and lastly my app. But I can't get any error from it.
Do you have any idea how I can perform these checks during build time or any other solution?

thanks

EDIT: I can't split in 3 projects even if it would be lot easier I know that!

Comment: To my mind you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Don't ask how to get a bad workaround for the splitting. Instead remove the obstacle avoiding you to split this into 3 projects and simply do it as intended by Eclipse and as everyone else would solve the same problem.

Comment: the obstacle was project management, decision wasn't mind. They gave me choice between smallpox and cholera

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you separate the project into three eclipse projects? If one package is completely independant, then (in my view) it doesn't belong into that project. And that goes to your package.common package as well. When it's a library project, then it could be separated thus implicitly solving your "separate build" problem.

As for the errors, I didn't could understand you well. What kind of errors do you mean? Import errors (e.g. visibility between packages) would be also generated when the project is divided into several projects with dependencies.

Comment: I know it would be easier but I can't do this

Comment: Then try copy the given packages into a temp folder, and use that folder to compile.